# How can I use pipe formatting in my type hints in Sphinx auto documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, type-hinting

I'm generating documentation for a library at work using Sphinx. In some of the type hints, we have this formatting:

```
 def find_and_read_ugrids(sim_node, query) -> tuple[UGrid3d | None, UGrid3d | None]:
```

I'm getting a typeerror in Sphinx due to this, and am not sure what's going on. The developer would like to leave the formatting the way it is, but `Optional(UGrid3d)` does work in the format's place. Is there any way I can get Sphinx to allow this type of type hint?

Comment: @dROOOze there are multiple lines in this project that are formatted similarly to this, but here is one example:  def find_and_read_ugrids(sim_node, query) -> tuple[UGrid3d | None, UGrid3d | None]:

Comment: Does your doc build pipeline where Sphinx is installed use recent python (3.10+)? If not, you're out of luck - just upgrade it, python version upgrade shouldn't be too complicated for documentation part only.